# Help with phpmyadmin import

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I apologize in advance if any of this is unclear. I'm a total noob to php and sql.

I threw some database files into my c:\Files folder and added

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'c:\Files';
```

to my config.inc.php. When I went back into phpmyadmin, I  selected a db, clicked import and was expecting to see an option to select those files now under some dropdown for like "web server upload" or something, no? I'm not seeing it. Only see the option to browse for a file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this info all check out: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#cfg_UploadDir

Comment: Where is your phpmyadmin running? On a local server? What is C:\Files pointing to?

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help guys. @Pekka, I'm running XAMPP locally. Not sure what you mean by "what is C:\Files pointing to?" The files directory just contains some .SQL files. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @LuxuryMode no, but if it's one server that is involved (local) it's clear. Strange, that should be okay

Comment: I feel like I screwed something with the installation directory when I installed XAMPP initially. Do I just delete the whole XAMPP folder to uninstall?

Comment: @matthewpavkov, i checked the $cfg['UploadDir'] string documentation and it seems to all check out.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that directory is where uploaded files are stored, not where phpmyadmin looks for uploaded files.

Just use the browse for file spot you found to upload the file you want to import.